# Vercel build error that doesn't happen locally

Tags: node.js, next.js, vercel, blitz.js

As the title says, I have a web app that build and runs fine locally, but gives me a weird error when I build with Vercel (cli or the website).
Here's what it normally (and should) look like for reference.

```
yarn run v1.22.19
warning ../package.json: No license field
warning ../../../package.json: No license field
$ blitz build
Loaded env from /home/sia/Documents/Projects/siarune.dev/.env.local
Loaded env from /home/sia/Documents/Projects/siarune.dev/.env
info  - Using webpack 5. Reason: Enabled by default https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/webpack5
info  - Generating route manifest  
info  - Checking validity of types  
info  - Using external babel configuration from /home/sia/Documents/Projects/siarune.dev/babel.config.js
info  - Creating an optimized production build ...Warning on line 7, column 2 of styles/index.module.sass: 
This selector doesn't have any properties and won't be rendered.
╷
7 │     max-height:fit-content
│     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
╵

info  - Creating an optimized production build .Warning on line 7, column 2 of styles/poetry.module.sass: 
This selector doesn't have any properties and won't be rendered.
╷
7 │     max-height:fit-content
│     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
╵

info  - Creating an optimized production build ...Warning on line 7, column 2 of styles/index.module.sass: 
This selector doesn't have any properties and won't be rendered.
╷
7 │     max-height:fit-content
│     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
╵

Warning on line 7, column 2 of styles/poetry.module.sass: 
This selector doesn't have any properties and won't be rendered.
╷
7 │     max-height:fit-content
│     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
╵

info  - Creating an optimized production build  
info  - Compiled successfully
info  - Collecting page data  
info  - Generating static pages (12/12)
info  - Finalizing page optimization  

Page                                Size     First Load JS
┌ ○ /                               1.55 kB         144 kB
├   └ css/7c5d5e51ff5d6a2b6e33.css  1.25 kB
├   /_app                           0 B             139 kB
├ ○ /404                            533 B           140 kB
├   └ css/7ca7b9c01475c154bcb8.css  390 B
├ λ /api/rpc/changePassword         0 B             139 kB
├ λ /api/rpc/forgotPassword         0 B             139 kB
├ λ /api/rpc/getCurrentUser         0 B             139 kB
├ λ /api/rpc/login                  0 B             139 kB
├ λ /api/rpc/logout                 0 B             139 kB
├ λ /api/rpc/resetPassword          0 B             139 kB
├ λ /api/rpc/signup                 0 B             139 kB
├ ○ /forgot-password                1.01 kB         140 kB
├ ○ /login                          511 B           140 kB
├ ● /projects/gug                   2.05 kB         145 kB
├   └ css/f5b237b4dfb47d0b0ae7.css  1.04 kB
├ ○ /projects/lotus                 512 B           140 kB
├ ● /projects/maboibart             2.04 kB         144 kB
├   └ css/93e49d8539b077a9cfb3.css  1.04 kB
├ ○ /projects/poetry                2.12 kB         145 kB
├   └ css/18ff7869d4a55b2a91d9.css  1.25 kB
├ ● /projects/sauce (313 ms)        2.04 kB         144 kB
├   └ css/2d34f9f47088b0f00230.css  1.06 kB
├ ○ /reset-password                 1.08 kB         140 kB
└ ○ /signup                         1.08 kB         140 kB
+ First Load JS shared by all       139 kB
├ chunks/framework.4fa35c.js      44.9 kB
├ chunks/main.8dc89c.js           54.1 kB
├ chunks/pages/_app.6429ea.js     39.3 kB
├ chunks/webpack.70ff54.js        866 B
└ css/d34792e57bbb2b6208a0.css    290 B

λ  (Server)  server-side renders at runtime (uses getInitialProps or getServerSideProps)
○  (Static)  automatically rendered as static HTML (uses no initial props)
●  (SSG)     automatically generated as static HTML + JSON (uses getStaticProps)
(ISR)     incremental static regeneration (uses revalidate in getStaticProps)

Done in 17.80s.
```

But when I use `vercel build` it says `Build optimization failed: found pages without a React Component as default export in`

```
Vercel CLI 27.2.0
> Loaded env from ".vercel/.env.preview.local"
WARNING: You should not upload the `.next` directory.
Installing dependencies...
yarn install v1.22.19
warning ../package.json: No license field
warning ../../../package.json: No license field
warning package-lock.json found. Your project contains lock files generated by tools other than Yarn. It is advised not to mix package managers in order to avoid resolution inconsistencies caused by unsynchronized lock files. To clear this warning, remove package-lock.json.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
success Already up-to-date.
$ prisma generate || true
Environment variables loaded from .env
Prisma schema loaded from db/schema.prisma

✔ Generated Prisma Client (3.16.0-integration-tmp-revert-node14.1 | library) to ./node_modules/@prisma/client in 84ms
You can now start using Prisma Client in your code. Reference: https://pris.ly/d/client

import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client'
const prisma = new PrismaClient()

Done in 2.70s.
Detected Next.js version: 11.1.0-0.45.4
Running "yarn run build"
yarn run v1.22.19
warning ../package.json: No license field
warning ../../../package.json: No license field
$ blitz build
Loaded env from /home/sia/Documents/Projects/siarune.dev/.env.local
Loaded env from /home/sia/Documents/Projects/siarune.dev/.env
info  - Using webpack 5. Reason: Enabled by default https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/webpack5
info  - Generating route manifest  
info  - Checking validity of types  
info  - Using external babel configuration from /home/sia/Documents/Projects/siarune.dev/babel.config.js
info  - Creating an optimized production build ...Warning on line 7, column 2 of styles/index.module.sass: 
This selector doesn't have any properties and won't be rendered.
╷
7 │     max-height:fit-content
│     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
╵

info  - Creating an optimized production build .Warning on line 7, column 2 of styles/poetry.module.sass: 
This selector doesn't have any properties and won't be rendered.
╷
7 │     max-height:fit-content
│     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
╵

info  - Creating an optimized production build .Warning on line 7, column 2 of styles/index.module.sass: 
This selector doesn't have any properties and won't be rendered.
╷
7 │     max-height:fit-content
│     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
╵

Warning on line 7, column 2 of styles/poetry.module.sass:
This selector doesn't have any properties and won't be rendered.
╷
7 │     max-height:fit-content
│     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
╵

info  - Creating an optimized production build
info  - Compiled successfully

> Build error occurred
Error: Build optimization failed: found pages without a React Component as default export in
pages/projects/gug
pages/projects/maboibart
pages/projects/sauce

See https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/page-without-valid-component for more info.

at /home/sia/Documents/Projects/siarune.dev/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:604:19
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/home/sia/Documents/Projects/siarune.dev/node_modules/next/dist/telemetry/trace/trace.js:60:20)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

All of the files that it says don't have an export clearly do

```
import Image from 'next/image'
import styles from 'styles/sauce.module.sass'
import chud from "styles/chud.module.sass"
import { serialize } from 'next-mdx-remote/serialize'
import { MDXRemote } from 'next-mdx-remote'
import { promises as fs } from 'fs'
import path from 'path'
import CluckHUD from 'app/core/components/CluckHUD'

export default function sauce({ source }: { source: any }) {
    return (
        <main className={styles.main}>
            <CluckHUD theme={chud.Forest} />
            <div className={styles.cont}>
                <div className={styles.hentWrap}>
                    <Image
                        src="/hentieSolid.png"
                        alt="bart"
                        height="100"
                        width="100"
                        layout="fixed"
                        className={styles.portrait}
                    />
                    <h1 className={styles.title}>Whatever This Place Is</h1>
                </div>

                <div className={styles.content}>
                    <MDXRemote {...source} components={components} className={styles.mdx} />
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
    );
}

const components = {}

export async function getStaticProps() {
    const mdPath = await path.join(process.cwd(), 'public/markdown/sauce.mdx');
    const rawMarkdown = await fs.readFile(mdPath, 'utf8');
    const postMd = await serialize(rawMarkdown);

    return { props: { source: postMd } }
}
```

Comment: Hi, did you figure out how to solve it? I have the same issue. I'm unable to get MDX work on Blitz.js. The error doesn't happen on localhost for me too. Cheers, mate.

Comment: GitHub issue: https://github.com/blitz-js/legacy-framework/issues/996

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could this be that you miss the uppercase on your component name?

Try `export default function Sauce` instead of `sauce`

Comment: That was most likely the issue, looking back. I've since consolidated them to dynamically fetch from a database, but the concept is the same.

Answer (score 0):

The build errors are most likely caused by mdx. This could be solved by upgrading Blitz.js, although 2.0 is still unstable and not recommended (by me, at least).
For now I've decided to use the down time to test out other frameworks I never tried, but you can do whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error for different reasons. The issue was that some generated types (prisma and gql) live in the `node_modules` folder. I needed to redeploy without the cache.

This can be done via the interface here

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you're using Prisma, and I had a similar issue using Prisma.

One caveat to prisma is that *generated types are not tracked in source control*

These need to be generated in CI before running `next build`

Make a command in `package.json` that says

`build-vercel: prisma generate && prisma migrate deploy && next build`

Vercel will pick it up and generate the types for you before building.

**In general: To troubleshoot why something doesn't build in CI when it works locally, try deleting everything non-tracked and building with your same command and environment variables**

Hope that helps.